# Проверка орфографии в TextBox и RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, проверка-орфографии

В [.NET 4.6.1 для WPF заявлена поддержка дополнительных языков проверки орфографии](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2015/10/29/wpf-in-net-4-6-1/), в том числе и русского. У кого-нибудь получилось включить эту орфографию для русского языка на контролах TextBox или RichTextBox? Очень не хочется возиться с кастомными словарями...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После очередного обновления Windows 10 (вроде кумулятивного 1511) проверка русской орфографии включилась в контролах TextBox и RichTextBox. Причем заработала и в проектах на фреймворке .NET 4.5.

При этом обнаружились некоторые нюансы:

1. TextBox может проверять только одним словарем. По-умолчанию берется словарь текущей культуры, но можно выставить самому другой язык через свойство Language.
2. RichTextBox умеет проверять несколькими словарями одновременно. Введенный смешанный русско-английский текст нормально проверялся и выдавал подсказки (suggestions) из разных словарей.
3. Если в RichTextBox текст вводится вручную, то проверка орфографии нормально отрабатывает. Если текст был задан в коде, то все слова подчеркиваются как неправильные и нет никаких подсказок. С этой проблемой сейчас разбираюсь.

Comment: Разобрался проблемой из п.3. Нужно вручную задавать свойство Language на добавляемых объектах типа Run. Видимо, при ручном вводе инфа о локали передается автоматически, и спеллчекер понимает какими словарями переводить.